# curdoc().add_root() causes bokeh plot rendering to fail silently

Tags: python, bokeh

The bokeh application below is intended to generate a random dataset when the button is pushed. I am trying to serve the app using the `bokeh.client` style, where there is one session that may be shared between simultaneous viewers.

If I include the line: `curdoc().add_root(column(p,button))` the plot will not be in the browser. I get a blank page with happy messages in JS console. If I remove it, I get a static plot, with no button. Can anyone explain what's wrong with my approach here?

I should add that the app works in the other server style with multiple distinct sessions. There I call `bokeh serve myapp.py` and don't make calls to the `session` object.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Button
from bokeh.client import push_session, pull_session

points = 100*np.random.rand(3,100)
points_x = points[0].tolist()
points_y = points[1].tolist()
p = figure(x_range=(0,100), y_range=(0,100))

circle_p = p.circle(x = points_x,
                    y = points_y, 
                    size = 20,
                    color = "navy", 
                    alpha = 0.5)

ds = circle_p.data_source

#callback function to update circles
def button_callback():
    new_data = dict()
    new_points = 100*np.random.rand(3,100)
    new_data['x'] = new_points[0].tolist()
    new_data['y'] = new_points[1].tolist()
    new_data['z'] = new_points[2].tolist()
    ds.data = new_data


#Add the button widget thingie to trigger the update
button = Button(label="Update")
button.on_click(button_callback)

# Put the button and plot in a layout in document
curdoc().add_root(column(p,button))

#create a session
session = push_session(curdoc())
session.show(p)
session.loop_until_closed()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want

```
session.show()
```

not

```
session.show(p)
```

Because you want to show the whole document, not just the plot. The first version works for me with Bokeh `0.12.6` (the latter also kind of works, but the plot is duplicated twice. My guess is you are using an older version that also had some layout bugs)

Comment: Yeah I was on 0.12.5. Thanks for the explanation.